# Is it possible to join two tables on one column = concatenation 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Table A has column X, which is an int made up of the concatenation of columns Y and Z (which are both floats) in table B. I want to join tables A and B in a manner similar to this:

```
select *
from tableA a inner join tableB b
on a.X = b.cast(concat(cast(b.Y as varchar), cast(b.Z as varchar)) as integer
```

Except that, obviously, my example is not correctly done.

Comment: What do you mean that an int is made by concatenating 2 floats? Can you provide an example? In general comparing floats for equality is not recommended.

Comment: I wonder how do you distinguish between `'1.4' + '22.8'` and `'1.42' + '2.8'`

Comment: And why on earth would you design this way? If you want to join, the data in both tables should match. If it doesn't then you have made a very bad design error and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: There actually were no numbers with decimals in the floats. They could have, and should have, been stored as ints.

Comment: @HLGEM- sometimes the design is not up to us...and we just need to figure out queries to deal with the design as is.

Comment: patient: doctor, it hurts when i move my arm like this
doctor: don't do that!

Comment: @dmr and sometimes you fix the datamodel rather than hacking it up with queries that are guaranteed to perform badly and which are subject to error. This is a simple fix with an additonal computed column. Too many people just give up on refactoring because it's the database when they would do no such thing if there was a bad design in the application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select * 
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b 
on a.X = cast(cast(b.Y as varchar) + cast(b.Z as varchar) as int)
```

If either of your floats have decimal points though, the conversion to `int` will fail.

E.g., this works:

```
declare @f1 as float
declare @f2 as float
set @f1 = 1
set @f2 = 7
select cast(cast(@f1 as varchar) + cast(@f2 as varchar) as int)
```

**Output:** `17`

But this does not:

```
declare @f1 as float
declare @f2 as float
set @f1 = 1.3
set @f2 = 7
select cast(cast(@f1 as varchar) + cast(@f2 as varchar) as int)
```

**Output:** `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.37' to data type int.`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for a computed column, then it would be index-able.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1682

Answer (score 2):

Can you create another column in b named x which contains the value you want?
Then the join to A is easy.